# Can't insert my data : PHP/MYSQL on Cloud9

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cloud9-ide

I'm on cloud9 for a school project and I am trying to test some MySQL query but it doesn't have new line in phpMyAdmin with this code.

When I try from an HTML form I have "Connection succefullyFOO", the "BAR" isn't echoed; what i do wrong?

```
<?php
//on se connecte à la base
$servername = getenv('IP');
$username = getenv('C9_USER');
$password = "";
$database = "projetPHP";
$dbport = 3306;

// Create connection
$bdd = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);


// Check connection
if ($bdd->connect_error) {die("Connection failed ".$bdd->connect_error);} 

echo "Connected successfully (".$bdd->host_info.")";
$pseudonyme = $_POST['pseudo'];
$mot_de_passe = $_POST['mdp'];
$confirm_mdp = $_POST['confirm_mdp'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if ($mot_de_passe == $confirm_mdp)
{
 //on crypte le mot de passe
 $mot_de_passe = sha1($mdp);

 echo "FOO";

 $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres(pseudonyme, mot_de_passe, email, date_inscription) VALUES(:pseudonyme, :mot_de_passe, :email, CURDATE())'
 $req->execute(array(
  ':pseudonyme' => $pseudonyme,
  ':mot_de_passe' => $mot_de_passe,
  ':email' => $email))
 echo "BAR";
}
?>
```

Comment: please show what error coming

Answer (score 2):

Placing an array in [`->execute( [array()] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is an `PDO` method.

In `mysqli` it is [`->execute( void )`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) where it does not accept parameters.

You need to use [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) before your `-execute()`

Try changing your code to

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres(pseudonyme, mot_de_passe, email, date_inscription) VALUES(?, ?, ?, CURDATE())');
$req->bind_param("sss", $pseudonyme, $mot_de_passe, $email);
$req->execute();
```

Comment: glad to help. make sure to mark it as answered to close the question.